# SD Bad Disc error

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card

I have an SD memory card. When I insert it, the computer can not find it. The Minitool Partition Wizard reports a bad disk and I can not do anything with it. I have tried `gparted`, `diskpart`, and `SD formatter` without success.

What can I do to save the files?

Answer (score 2):

I would try inserting the card in a second computer, to rule out the possibility that it's some kind of software or driver issue.  I have occasionally had issues with USB devices in the past where it turned out the computer I was using was the source of the problem, not the device. (This could be true even when other USB devices work on that computer.)

Answer (score 1):

The best advise would be to try it in a different reader.  This could be on a different machine, an external card reader on the same machine, a digital camera, etc.  If you've tried it in multiple locations and nothing can detect the card, then I'd say it's dead.  In this case, I don't think anything short of hacking the card to get at the memory chip directly would work (and not even that, if the chip is what failed).

If another device is able to see the card, you might be able to copy the files off of it that way.  Even if it's via a camera or similar device, you can usually connect the device to a computer via USB and read the files.  If the card can be seen by another device but there are no files or the drive can't be mounted by your operating system, you still might be able to recover files using a disk recovery software, [like those listed here](http://lifehacker.com/5237503/five-best-free-data-recovery-tools). I have used [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to successfully repair/recover files on SD cards before.